# how to create a share memory pool in windows

Tags: c++, windows, file-mapping

I want to make a share memory pool for all the other process to share the data, but after I read about the CreateFileMapping API document, I was confused about that it will need to specify the size of the share memory. I actually want it to be dynamic allocate and free which looks more like a service. Is there some way to do the share memory dynamic using createFileMapping or not?

Comment: If Boost is available to you, use Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: SEC_RESERVE option should allow you to reserve address space without commiting it, but from API it looks like you want be able to free it.

Comment: thanks, luskan. It's some sort of share memory pool, and I have already done it with Boost.I am now developing for the system without boost, so I need to know how to do that. Now I am solving that with allocate new memory with CreateFileMapping each time. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Named Shared Memory.

**First Process**

The first process creates the file mapping object by calling the `CreateFileMapping` function with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and a name for the object. By using the `PAGE_READWRITE` flag, the process has read/write permission to the memory through any file views that are created.
Then the process uses the file mapping object handle that `CreateFileMapping` returns in a call to `MapViewOfFile` to create a view of the file in the process address space. The `MapViewOfFile` function returns a pointer to the file view, `pBuf`. The process then uses the CopyMemory function to write a string to the view that can be accessed by other processes.

Process 1 code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR szMsg[]=TEXT("Message from first process.");

int _tmain()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 szName);                 // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }
   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
                        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                        0,
                        0,
                        BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

       CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }


   CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    _getch();

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   return 0;
}
```

**Second Process**

A second process can access the string written to the shared memory by the first process by calling the `OpenFileMapping` function specifying the same name for the mapping object as the first process. Then it can use the `MapViewOfFile` function to obtain a pointer to the file view, `pBuf`. The process can display this string as it would any other string. In this example, the message box displayed contains the message "Message from first process" that was written by the first process.

Process 2 code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

int _tmain()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }

   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
               0,
               0,
               BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }

   MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   return 0;
}
```

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx